# React Native TextInput does not get focus

Tags: react-native

I have this simple code of a `TextInput` that I want it to get focus when it first renders and on submits. However, it does not get focus at all.

```
render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        ref={(c) => this._input = c}
        style={[styles.item, this.props.style]}
        placeholder={"New Skill"}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({text})
        }}
        onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
          this.props.onSubmitEditing(this.state.text);
          this._input.clear();
          this._input.focus();
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._input.focus();
  }
```

Comment: Is it get focused or not get focused?

Comment: Oh hey sorry about my wording. I want it to get focused but it does not.

Comment: change this `ref={(c) => this._input = c}` to `ref={(c) => { this._input = c }}` and see if its gonna work

Comment: No it still does not get focused

Comment: Then please try using [`autoFocus`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autofocus) prop.

Comment: could you try to wrap focus inside `setTimeOut` function like:
`setTimeout(() => this._input.focus(), 250);`

Comment: Thank you @IPutuYogaPermana  that worked!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So my assumption is true. Try to focus is failed, `this._input` doesn't contain anything when `componentDidMount` called, because `render` function still not called yet and no reference for it.

So the solution for now is **delay** it a little bit until render function already called.

Thats why wrap the code inside `setTimeout` function quite helpful. Anyway i admit it, it is a little bit tricky. Would be great if someone find the better way.

```
componentDidMount() {
   setTimeout(() => this._input.focus(), 250);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is the unique i found to be working. But componentDidMount() is called after the render() method, so your explanation is wrong. Also, you can set the timeout to 0 and the solution still works. I am very curious about the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: Has anyone tested this with iOS, or specifically iOS - Web... I've tried this approach and it works great for android and android - web but doesn't seem to work for iOS or iOS - web.

Answer (score 2):

You can use autoFocus property of TextInput and set it to true. It will focus TextInput on componentDidMount automatically.I tested it and it's focusing input on both componentDidMount and onSubmitEditing.

```
render() {
return (
  <TextInput
    ref={(c) => this._input = c}
    placeholder={"New Skill"}
    autoFocus={true}
    onChangeText={(text) => {
      this.setState({text})
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
      this.props.onSubmitEditing(this.state.text);
      this._input.clear();
      this._input.focus();
    }}
  />
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
  const inputRef: LegacyRef<TextInput> = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        inputRef.current?.focus();
      }, 0);
    }
  });
```